# Using split function multiple times with tweepy result in IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using `split` function and it fails on `data` and gives me the error:

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Data equals to:

```
1457410676.51::RT @robbwolf: Earthquake in Reno! Wacky. 1457410777.98::13:19 #\u5730\u9707 #earthquake https:\/\/t.co\/2X8FaipZsW 1457410814.04::1.7 magnitude #earthquake. 12 mi from Anza, #CA, United States https:\/\/t.co\/1GWexXmLom 1457410819.04::1.7 magnitude #earthquake. 12 mi from #Anza, CA, United States https:\/\/t.co\/fL5MDx7bhS
```

Code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time

ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            location = data.split(',"location":"')[1].split('","url')[0]
            saveThis=str(time.time())+ '::' + tweet
            saveFile = open('locandtext.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(saveThis)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'Failed on data' , str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream (auth , Listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["Earthquake"] )
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: i want to get location, time and tweets and save in csv file. I am getting tweets by using data.split but unable to get location.

Comment: Can you please post your sample data?

Comment: 1457410676.51::RT @robbwolf: Earthquake in Reno! Wacky. 
1457410777.98::13:19  #\u5730\u9707 #earthquake https:\/\/t.co\/2X8FaipZsW
1457410814.04::1.7 magnitude #earthquake. 12 mi from Anza, #CA, United States https:\/\/t.co\/1GWexXmLom
1457410819.04::1.7 magnitude #earthquake. 12 mi from #Anza, CA, United States https:\/\/t.co\/fL5MDx7bhS

Comment: Thank you i have obtained correct output now

Answer (score 0):

The value of `data` doesn't contain the token `,"text":"`, therefore the result of `split` is one item list - which includes the entire text.

To avoid `IndexError` verify `,"text":"` appears in `data`:

```
token = ',"text":"'
if token in data:
    text = data.split(token)[1]
```